# What does &HF7 mean in vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I've been searching Google for awhile and on this site but I can't figure out what &HF7 means? Can someone please explain? Sorry if its a dumb question. I'm very new to this stuff...

Here is the code I'm studying.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Key = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"
DigitalID = WshShell.RegRead(key & "DigitalProductId")

ProductName = "Product Name: " & WshShell.RegRead(Key & "ProductName") & vbNewLine
ProductID = "Product ID: " & WshShell.RegRead(Key & "ProductID") & vbNewLine
ProductKey = "Installed Key: " & ConvertToKey(DigitalID)
ProductID = ProductName & ProductID & ProductKey

If vbYes = MsgBox(ProductId & vblf & vblf & "Save to a file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Windows Key Information") then
   Save ProductID
End if

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
    Const KeyOffset = 52
    isWin8 = (Key(66) \ 6) And 1
    Key(66) = (Key(66) And &HF7) Or ((isWin8 And 2) * 4)
    i = 24
    Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
    Do
        Cur = 0
        X = 14
        Do
            Cur = Cur * 256
            Cur = Key(X + KeyOffset) + Cur
            Key(X + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24)
            Cur = Cur Mod 24
            X = X -1
        Loop While X >= 0
        i = i -1
        KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
        Last = Cur
    Loop While i >= 0
    If (isWin8 = 1) Then
        keypart1 = Mid(KeyOutput, 2, Last)
        insert = "N"
        KeyOutput = Replace(KeyOutput, keypart1, keypart1 & insert, 2, 1, 0)
        If Last = 0 Then KeyOutput = insert & KeyOutput
    End If
    a = Mid(KeyOutput, 1, 5)
    b = Mid(KeyOutput, 6, 5)
    c = Mid(KeyOutput, 11, 5)
    d = Mid(KeyOutput, 16, 5)
    e = Mid(KeyOutput, 21, 5)
    ConvertToKey = a & "-" & b & "-" & c & "-" & d & "-" & e
End Function

Function Save(Data)
    Const ForWRITING = 2
    Const asASCII = 0
    Dim fso, f, fName, ts
    fName = "Windows Key.txt"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.CreateTextFile fName
    Set f = fso.GetFile(fName)
    Set f = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForWRITING, asASCII)
    f.Writeline Data
    f.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a public constant: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?277384-VB-Key-COnsts

Typically used to detect modifier keys being held (ctrl, alt etc)

http://microsoft.public.word.vba.general.narkive.com/28vVYW5c/detect-modifier-keys-from-vba

That specific one is Public Const VK_CRSEL which I assume to be Ctrl select.

Comment: I think this answer has been accepted too quickly. &HF7 is this code looks like a [mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) to me.

Comment: I concur that the usage of &HF7 [hex] (dec 247, bin 11110111), in this case, is a mask (bitmask) for a bitwise operation.

Answer (score 2):

It's the number `247`.

In VBScript, the `&H` prefix indicates a hexadecimal number, similar to the `0x` prefix in C/C++. The number is `F7`, which is equivalent of the decimal value `247`.

Answer (score 2):

`&HF7` is used as a mask here.
The byte in position 66 of the array Key is compared with the byte &HF7
Written in binary form &HF7 becomes 11110111. If you "And" the value of Key(66) with 11110111 then you'll get a new byte made up of all the bits in Key(66) except the bit in the 4th position from the right.

For example if Key(66) is 10101010 then 10101010 And 11110111 will be 10100010.

Comment: Not only is this the correct answer, this one has the most relevant example. I think this deserves the title "best answer".